# Share button for mobile website to invoke iOS/Android system share dialogs

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

Is it possible to create a share button (link) in my website that can invoke share dialogs in iOS and Android systems?

I mean the following dialog for each system:

[image]

[image]

I am not asking of how to do it by using iOS/Android SDKs. I want it with only HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Here is the link for it https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

First create html page and put below code in a button

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Now, create a webpage in android.

```
WebView myWebView;
    WebSettings webSettings;
    WebAppInterface webInterface;
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webInterface=new WebAppInterface(MainActivity.this);

        webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(webInterface, "Android");
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("Your url for that html file you created");
```

Now create a class which will listen to your callback
above line addJavascriptInterface() is responsible for callback

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Remember String is case sensitive,and android require  @JavascriptInterface interface for calling android functionality

Comment: This is Android ONLY.

Comment: This is not HTML/javascript

Comment: Only came here because of HTML/JavaScript

Answer (score 31):

#### Use the [**Web Share API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) to share your URL on iOS or Android via Javascript.

It is supported by

- [Chrome since Version 61 (2016)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share) and
- iOS 12.2 is told to add support for it soon (2019).

```js
const shareButton = document.getElementById("answer-example-share-button"); 
shareButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => { 
  if (navigator.share) {
    navigator.share({
        title: 'Web Share API Draft',
        text: 'Take a look at this spec!',
        url: 'https://wicg.github.io/web-share/#share-method',
      })
      .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
      .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
  } else {
    console.log('Share not supported on this browser, do it the old way.');
  }
});
```

```html
<button id='answer-example-share-button'>Share!</button>
```

Citing [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share):

- you must be served over HTTPS
- you can only invoke the API in response to a user action, such as a click (e.g., you can't call navigator.share as part of the page load)
- you can also share any URL, not just URLs under your website's current scope: and you may also share text without a URL
- you should feature-detect it in case it's not available on your users' platform (e.g., via navigator.share !== undefined)

Comment: This is great, thanks @flob. BTW, if you don't use jQuery, this is almost as easy with JS: `const shareButton = document.getElementById("share-button");
shareButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  ...`

Answer (score 0):

Yes now you can share it with Javascript for Android. Follow link if you need more details or say thanks

https://sdtuts.com/javascript-android-native-share-popup-navigator-share-api/

```
async function AndroidNativeShare(Title,URL,Description){
  if(typeof navigator.share==='undefined' || !navigator.share){
    alert('Your browser does not support Android Native Share');
  } else {
    const TitleConst = Title;
    const URLConst = URL;
    const DescriptionConst = Description;

    try{
      await navigator.share({title:TitleConst, text:DescriptionConst, url:URLConst});
    } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error sharing: ' + error);
    return;
    }   
  }
} 

$(".share_button").click(function(){
  AndroidNativeShare('My Page Title', 'https://sdtuts.com','This is description'); 
});
```