# Share toast on android or ios open after someone click share button on my website

Tags: javascript, android

I am looking for something like this [Share button for mobile website to invoke iOS/Android system share dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176004/share-button-for-mobile-website-to-invoke-ios-android-system-share-dialogs) Answer#2 WebShareAPI
but as I am not from technical background I dont understand how to put this script

```
$('#answer-example-share-button').on('click', () => {
  if (navigator.share) {
    navigator.share({
        title: 'Web Share API Draft',
        text: 'Take a look at this spec!',
        url: 'https://wicg.github.io/web-share/#share-method',
      })
      .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
      .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
  } else {
    console.log('Share not supported on this browser, do it the old way.');
  }
});
```

I am using blogger on this [website](https://packswallpaper.blogspot.com/) and want to implement a share toast which actiate after someone click the share button next to download button.
If any method to share a particular "image url" is possible then also provide me that.
Anyway, TIA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share button for mobile website to invoke iOS/Android system share dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176004/share-button-for-mobile-website-to-invoke-ios-android-system-share-dialogs)

Comment: actually that is the answer but I want to know how to add the script on blogger?